# Add or Edit relation fields in Content Manager of Strapi

Tags: strapi

I am building a simple recipe website by Strapi. Now I want to make one `Recipe` has so many `Ingredient`. Therefore, there are two collections, They are in Many way relationship (Since I don't need to point back or link back to `Recipe`)

However, in Content Manager, I have to create some `Ingredient` items before creating one `Recipe`.
Is it possible to create or edit `Ingredient` while create `Recipe` in the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using `components` in `strapi`. So basically, you'll need to create a `Recipe` collection and `Ingredient` component, and link to the component to `Recipe` collection as a repeatable component. So this way when you create a `Recipe` entry, you'll be able to add/edit the ingredients entries on the fly.

Have a look at this [link](https://docs.strapi.io/user-docs/content-type-builder/creating-new-content-type#creating-a-new-component) to learn how to create a component.

Once you've created the component, follow the steps below to link it to the `Recipe` collection:

1. Edit the `Recipe` collection and add an existing `component`.
   [image]
2. Set the component as a `Repeating component`.
   [image]
3. Your model configuration should look similar to this.
   [image]
4. Save the changes to the `Recipe` collection and then try creating an entry. You'll be presented with the following user interface that lets you edit/add ingredients on the fly.
   [image]
5. Publish the entries and hit the find API will the `populate` key in URL like so:
   `http://localhost:1337/api/receipes?populate=ingredients`

Comment: Hey the strapi link is dead

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. `Strapi` team has update the documentation, hence the 404 error. I've updated the link now.